# How to write Presto Query to get the latest date from when a item has non zero inventory?

Tags: sql, hive, presto, trino

I have a table named item_inventory which include items and day on day inventory. like below

| City | inventory | invDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 0 | 3/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 0 | 4/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 1 | 5/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 1 | 6/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 0 | 7/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 0 | 8/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 1 | 9/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 1 | 10/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 1 | 11/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 1 | 12/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 1 | 13/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 1 | 14/1/2021 |
| Item1 | 1 | 15/1/2021 |

What I need is the date on which an item has zero inventory but has inventory for next 3 days and so on.

Sample output should be:

| City | lst_soldout |
| --- | --- |
| Item1 | 8/1/2021 |

as item1 has zero inventory on 8th Jan and having inventory for next 3 days.

Comment: Why does the `city` column contain item names? Can the date column have gaps in it? If it can, should a missing date be treated as zero inventory? If an item (city?) has multiple sold out dates, do you just want the latest one? *(Your question title says you do, but your question text is worded differently.)*

Answer (score 2):

> What I need is the date on which an item has zero inventory but has inventory for next 3 days and so on.

If you don't have gaps in days then you can use window functions to calculate rolling sum of the following 3 days of inventory:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (City, inventory, invDate) as (
    values ('Item1', 0, '3/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 0, '4/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 1, '5/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 1, '6/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 0, '7/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 0, '8/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 1, '9/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 1, '10/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 1, '11/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 1, '12/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 1, '13/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 1, '14/1/2021'),
    ('Item1', 1, '15/1/2021')
),

-- query parts
date_parsed as (
    select City, inventory,
           date_parse(invDate, '%e/%c/%Y') invDate
    from dataset
),
folowing_calculated as (
    select *,
           sum(if(inventory > 0, 1)) over (
                partition by City
                order by invDate
                rows between 1 following and 3 following) following_with_inv
    from date_parsed
)

select City, invDate lst_soldout
from folowing_calculated
where inventory = 0 and following_with_inv = 3;
```

Output:

```
 City  |       lst_soldout
-------+-------------------------
 Item1 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00.000
```

If you have several such lines per city and you want a single one then you can add grouping by City and selecting the max date:

```
select City, max(invDate) lst_soldout
from folowing_calculated
where inventory = 0 and following_with_inv = 3
group by City;
```

Comment: @MatBailie updated the answer with corresponding SQL and description.